# How to get the name of a table in MS access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one table that has a list of Facilities, then I have many other tables, one for each Facility with the equipment that is there.

I am trying to make a query that can bring all of these tables together. The problem is that equipment names can be repeated from Facility to Facility so I need to get the Facility name to be associated with the equipment to have unique records. I do not have the ability to edit these equipment tables so I can't just add a column to the table and the only place that the Facility name is referenced in the Equipment Tables is in the title of the Table itself.

Is there any way that I can link the Facility Table records to the names of the Equipment Tables?

The Tables are similar to this:

Facilities

- Column1
- EI-456
- EI-497

EI-456

- Column1
- Pump1
- Pump2
- FT1

EI-497

- Column1
- TT1
- Pump1
- Riser1

Hopefully that makes it a little more clear.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show us the table definitions and format your question for better readability.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like terrible design. You should have:

- a Facilities table
- an Equipments table (optional, depending on your needs)
- a Locations table (or Assignment or...) where you just store the FacilityId and the EquipmentId.

I suggest that you read a bit about **database normalisation**. That will really pay off in the long run.

Comment: So true, decent design is where to start.

Comment: If I had developed the Database I would've made it nice. The equipment Tables are generated and updated with a third party program so I don't have any control over the structure. Blame Siemens for that one haha.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for can be done dynamically through code (vba, etc) using your row record value to populate column.name in a query string.

I'd run an initial query to determine the facility name and then do:

Dim sillyString as String

sillyString = .row(?).item("column") = "EI-456"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & sillyString & "WHERE ..."